# SQL Create Columns From values and fill with other column

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I want to take values from 1 column, and turn them into headers for another. Its easier to show you:

Initial Table:

```
Name      | Label   | Value
Tom Jones | January | 42
Rick James| March   | 83
```

Ending Table:

```
Name      | January | March
Tom Jones | 42      | NULL
Rick James| NULL    | 83
```

The format is needed like this because of the type of sorting and ordering that I am doing on the Label.

UPDATE:
When I mention multiple columns for value I mean something like:

```
Name      | Label_1   | ValueA_1 | ValueB_1 | Label_2 | ValueA_2 | ValueB_2
Tom Jones | January   | 42       | 77       | March   | 99       | 22
Rick James| March     | 83       | 17       | May     | NULL     | 112
```

Comment: To take it further, there is the situation where there are multiple columns for `Value` and I would want to `GROUP_CONCAT()` them or something within that Label heading.

Comment: You want to create new table or just select data with such column names?

Comment: Select the data. Basically I need the values for a time range comma separated within their time range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CREATE TABLE NewTable AS SELECT ...`:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable
SELECT
  NAme, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Label = 'January' THEN value  END) AS January,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Label = 'March' THEN value END) AS March
FROM tablename AS t1
GROUP BY Name;
```

This will create a brand new table `newTable` with the same structure of the `SELECT` statement.

---

**Update:**

Based on your comment, if you want to get the values of `value` comma separated:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable
SELECT
  Name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Label = 'January' THEN value  END) AS January,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Label = 'March' THEN value  END) AS March
FROM table1 AS t1
GROUP BY Name;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73f3c/1)

---

### Update:

If you want to do this dynamically, not hardcoding the values, you have to use dynamic sql to do so, like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('GROUP_CONCAT(IF(Label = ''',
      Label, ''', value, NULL)) AS ', '''', Label , '''')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Table1 ;

SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE newTable ',
                  'SELECT Name,' ,
                  @sql, ' FROM table1 ',
                  ' GROUP BY Name');


prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a070/1)

Comment: But you are hardcoding the headings, not pulling them from the data

Comment: @Raymond - Do you want to do this dynamically for any data in the `Label` column?